# Kotlin Script Change Timeout

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea

I use a Kotlin Scratch File (.kts) in IntelliJ IDEA.
Running this file will be stopped after 30 seconds. 
How can I change the timeout of a scratch file?

Comment: The timeout is defined here: https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/75f1fb0237b6c248643ba3cb7013ea2750247659/idea/idea-jvm/src/org/jetbrains/kotlin/idea/scratch/compile/KtScratchExecutionSession.kt.191#L40    so I think you have to change it and then compile it and use it inside your IDE

Comment: Please vote for this ticket to be implemented: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-38459